# GCC on MSYS2 produces PIE by Default Without --enable-default-pie

Tags: gcc, msys2

So, im trying to compile linux kernel 3.0.1 on MSYS2, and gcc ALWAYS produces PIE executables
for some reason breaking the makefile. ive tryed many solutions, like patching the makefile.
but it just wont work, gcc -v produces

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /c/S/gcc/src/gcc-11.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.3.0 (GCC)
```

and umane -mrs produces

```
MSYS_NT-10.0-19045 3.4.6.x86_64 x86_64
```

What am i doing wrong here?

i tryed this patch:

```
 all: vmlinux

+# force no-pie for distro compilers that enable pie by default
+KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie)
+KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -no-pie)
+KBUILD_AFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie)
+KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie)
+
```